# Can't delete files with special (and odd) filename characters

Tags: special-characters, inode

I was cleaning up my NAS and found this odd situation.

```
$ pwd
/Volumes/Backup/NoteHP/Outras/Ed Motta

$ ls -larit
total 12932
 7786751625 -rwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff  3388293 Feb  2  2005 Ed Motta & Seu Jorge_Tem espaço na van.mp3
10229559116 -rwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff  3199086 Jul 13  2011 Ed Motta & Flávio Venturini - Nascente .mp3
 7737291939 drwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff    16384 Mar 14 00:21 .
 5442442802 drwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff    16384 Mar 14 00:26 ..

$ rm *
rm: Ed Motta & Flávio Venturini - Nascente .mp3: No such file or directory
rm: Ed Motta & Seu Jorge_Tem espaço na van.mp3: No such file or directory

$ ls -larit | cat -vet
total 12932$
 7786751625 -rwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff  3388293 Feb  2  2005 Ed Motta & Seu Jorge_Tem espaço na van.mp3$
10229559116 -rwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff  3199086 Jul 13  2011 Ed Motta & Fla?M-^Avio Venturini - Nascente .mp3$
 7737291939 drwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff    16384 Mar 14 00:21 .$
 5442442802 drwx------  1 rjdsantos  staff    16384 Mar 14 00:26 ..$
```

I tried almost everything:

```
find . -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -inum XXX -exec rm -f {} \;
find . -inum XXX -delete
```

The NAS is an Seagate Blackarmor 110 (firmware up-to-date) with one disk of 2TB, mounted by CIFS. Running Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 (up-to-date, too). I avoid using WiFi because of connection problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens for example when you:  rm "Ed Motta & Flávio Venturini - Nascente .mp3"  with the quotes.

Comment: What happens if you `cd ..` and `rm -r "Ed Motta"`?  Is there any possibility of mounting this file system on a computer running a different operating system (e.g., [ugh] Windows)?

Comment: Try **rm "Ed Motta & S*"** and **rm "Ed Motta & F*"**.